# Pass test data to nested struct

Tags: go

I am trying to get to grips with testing in Go and I have hit a bit of a stumbling block.

I have the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

type ConformanceChange struct {
    Val   string
    Proxy struct {
        Address string
        Port    string
    }
}

func Item(conformance ConformanceChange) string {
    service := conformance.Proxy.Address
    services := map[string]string{
        "Word": "Now",
    }
    service = services[service]
    fmt.Println("Service: ", service)
    return service
}

func Test_Item(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        conformance ConformanceChange
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name string
        args args
        want string
    }{
        // TODO: Add test cases.
        {name: "empty", args: args{
            conformance: ConformanceChange{},
        }, want: ""},
        {name: "value", args: args{
            conformance: ConformanceChange{Val: "test", Proxy: {Address: "d", Port: "d"}},
        }, want: ""},
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            if got := Item(tt.args.conformance); got != tt.want {
                t.Errorf("getService() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to pass data to `ConformanceChange.Proxy.Address` when running my tests. I can pass data to `ConformanceChange.Val` and it works.

Can someone please let me know the correct syntax for this?

**Update**
The solution provided by Bless worked.

Following on from this, if I had the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

type ConformanceChange struct {
    Val   string
    Proxy struct {
        Address string `json:address`
        Port    string `json:port`
    }
}

func Item(conformance ConformanceChange) string {
    service := conformance.Proxy.Address
    services := map[string]string{
        "Word": "Now",
    }
    service = services[service]
    fmt.Println("Service: ", service)
    return service
}

func Test_Item(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        conformance ConformanceChange
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name string
        args args
        want string
    }{
        // TODO: Add test cases.
        {name: "empty", args: args{
            conformance: ConformanceChange{},
        }, want: ""},
        {name: "value", args: args{
            conformance: ConformanceChange{Val: "test", Proxy: struct {
                Port    string `json:port`
            }(struct {
                Port    string
            }{Port: "d"})},
        }, want: ""},
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            if got := Item(tt.args.conformance); got != tt.want {
                t.Errorf("getService() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I don't want to specify all the fields in my test (as it could get messy), can I just specify the one? In the above code it fails with:
`Cannot use 'struct { Port string` json:port `}(struct { Port string }{Port: "d"})' (type struct {...}) as the type struct {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a struct value, the struct should be specified.

```
{name: "value", args: args{
    conformance: ConformanceChange{Val: "test", Proxy: struct{Address string; Port string}{Address: "d", Port: "d"}},
}, want: ""},
```

To avoid repetition, you could define a `Proxy` struct

```
type Proxy struct {
    Address string
    Port    string
}

type ConformanceChange struct {
    Val   string
    Proxy Proxy
}
```

and then refer to it when initialising the struct value

```
{name: "value", args: args{
    conformance: ConformanceChange{Val: "test", Proxy: Proxy{Address: "d", Port: "d"}},
}, want: ""},
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes that worked!
Ideally I would have used two structs but in my real-world scenario I am ingesting the data from somewhere that I have no control over

Comment: I have progressed further here and was wondering if there is a way to not have to specify all the fields in my test cases (I have updated my question to reflect this)?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your updated question. But if your question was whether it is possible to do this without updating the original struct `ConformanceChange`, you could define another struct type inside (or outside) the test function and use that instead. As long as the struct fields match, you won't need to update the original struct. Here is a playground link - https://play.golang.org/p/k8UAgBA2C88.